# Type 'HashSet' is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have written a simple aspx code in vb.net but getting the following error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'HashSet' is not defined.

Please note that System.Collections.Generic is included in the aspx file but still i m getting the error. **HashSet** is a part of System.Collection.Generic and i have import it but don't know why i am getting this error

Any idea how you resolve this issue ?

### Code

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<script language="VB" runat="server">

'Relative file path to XML data
Dim strXmlFilePath as String = Server.MapPath("quiz.xml")

Dim xDoc as XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Dim intTotalQuestion As UShort
    Dim intQuestionNo As UShort = 0
    Dim intScore As UShort = 0
    Dim arrAnswerHistory As New ArrayList()
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder
    Dim builderS1 As New StringBuilder
    Dim intTotalQuestionToDisplay As UShort
    Dim result As New List(Of UShort)()


    Public Sub randomFunc()
        Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim loopValue As UShort = intTotalQuestionToDisplay - 1


       Dim check As New HashSet(Of UShort)()
        For i As UShort = 0 To loopValue
            Dim curValue As Integer = rand.[Next](1, intTotalQuestionToDisplay)
            While check.Contains(curValue)
                curValue = rand.[Next](1, intTotalQuestionToDisplay)
            End While
            result.Add(curValue)
            check.Add(curValue)
        Next
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? Look at the target-framework setting in your project. `HashSet(Of T)` was new in 3.5 (VS 2008). Why don't you use codebehind? Side-note: `randomFunc` will produce the same questions if called from a loop since the `Random` instance is created there from the system-time.

Comment: I am using window 8.1 but the page is using AppPool of v2.0(Integerated)

Comment: How to use CodeBehind ? Any good link

Comment: I don't know if it's good but it's the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx When the app-pool uses 2.0 you don't have `HashSet<T>`. Can you change it to `3.5` or newer?

Comment: I am taking about v2.0 in IIS. Their only 2 CLR version appears i.e. V2.0 and v4.0. I am using AppPool of v2.0(integrated)

Comment: What means "appears i.e. V2.0 and v4.0"? If you have 4.0 why don't you enable it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter He's saying that there are only two versions avaiable to choose from when configuring an application pool: V2.0 and V4.0. @user288645 Tim's right. Just enable the V4.0 CLR for your AppPool and you can use `HashSet(Of T)`

Comment: I cant move to v4.0.  This code chunk will be part of Dotnetnuke version 6, which ran on V2.0. I was taking about CLR version that appear when a pool is created. Their V2.0 and V4.0 version exist. Please note that .Net Framework 3.5 is installed on the OS.

Comment: Is there any alternative to HashSet ?

Comment: If you cannot upgrade your compiled version to .NET 4, you might look at creating an array and only adding unique values to it (or creating an array and pulling unique values out). http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/207d67e8-70a9-4ec2-a8b2-f7d13e8dbd89/put-only-unique-items-in-the-array?forum=csharpgeneral